# Sigma sign in haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I realize sth. like the sigma sign in haskell?

What I want to compute is this:

http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/dulfkvz8/form.png

EDIT: I don't want to represent the greek character. I want to compute the sum.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to make use of the greek letter in your program's source code, or do you want to sum something?

Comment: not the greek letter, I want to sum sth up.

Comment: I would recommend not using the word "sign" in your title, if what you're looking for is not the actual sigma character.

Comment: I'm not sure the link is correct; do you mean `(x{sub i}, x{sub i+1))`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you have the `x` values in a (non-emtpy) list `xs = [x1, x2, ... xn]`, you can write it as

```
sum $ zipWith fn xs (tail xs)
```

Comment: For this particular problem, this is probably the way to go.

Comment: For me this looks very Advanced. maybe there is a more Basic way to implememt this?

Comment: It's probably less advanced than you think.  The function `zipWith` takes 3 arguments: the first argument is a function (`fn`) and the second and third arguments are lists.  If you check the online documentation, you will see that `zipWith` uses the function argument to combine the elements in the two lists pairwise, and returns the results as a list (whose length is as long as the shorter input list).

Comment: And when you use `zipWith` in conjunction with `tail`, like here, you get to apply your function `fn` to every 'adjacent' pair in the list.

Comment: Due to the high rating I marked this answer as the solution, although I ended up using a recursion.

Comment: You do realize that it is an `x` subscript, not an `i` subscript on the second argument to `fn`. Thus, this does not compute what the equations states. (Unless of course it is a typo in the equation.)

Comment: Good observation, trinithis :D I think, though, it's safe to assume that it's a typo, as the `x` in the subset is an undefined free variable here (I've seen examples in where the same name `x` was used, but `x`-that-always-has-a-subscript was different from `x`-always-without-subscript) or just nonsensical.

Answer (score -3):

Why not a simple recursive function?

```
sigma 0 fn = fn 
sigma i fn = fn + (sigma (i-1) fn)
```

Comment: Note that this approach (naive recursion) has rather horrid behaviour for longer sequences. Also, this particular implementation just is just `fn * (i + 1)` for `n >= 0` and an infinite loop for `i < 0` (you'd have to make `fn` a function of `i` an actually call it at each step).